Is there any standard request for attached content-disposition with filename?
I have an endpoint produces pretty big octet-stream.
// produces application/octet-stream
Flux<DataBuffer> readFileContent(
        final ServerWebExchange exchange) {
}

And I changed the endpoint to produce the data with the Content-Disposition header, with two request parameters.
Flux<DataBuffer> readFileContent(
        final ServerWebExchange exchange,
        @RequestParam(value = "attachment", required = false)
        final Boolean attachment,
        @RequestParam(value = "filename", required = false)
        final String filename) {
    // put Content-Disposition; attachment; filename=<filename>
} 

It works as expected. What I want to know is,
Is there any standard way, for client, to requesting the Content-Disposition other than above example with ?attachment=true&filename=a.zip?

I don’t think so but there’s the prefer header

What kind of client are you talking about specifically? I assume your goal is to trigger a download. An <a> link has a download attribute that can trigger this behavior for example.
